# Exclude @SpringBootApplication from component scanning

Tags: spring-boot, component-scan

I have two classes marked as `@SpringBootApplication` under one directory:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FirstSpringBootApplication
```

and

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SecondSpringBootApplication
```

`@SpringBootApplication` annotation contains `@ComponentScan` annotation and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation. So, each of two of these classes will consider another as `@Configuration` bean. How to exclude `FirstSpringBoodApplication` from component scanning by `SecondSpringBootApplication` **without** using profiles?

Comment: Try to check if this works for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you need to define two or more excludeFilters criteria, you have to use the array.

For instances in this section of code I want to exclude all the classes in the org.xxx.yyy package and another specific class, MyClassToExclude

Answer (score 2):

The annotate class with below annotations will work similarly as `@SpringBootApplication`. It also does the same, and the `excludeFilter` is important, which is used to specify which class not to include while scanning.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={@Filter(type=CUSTOM, classes={TypeExcludeFilter.class})})
```