# How to exclude bean from loading?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem integrating external library with Spring. It contains a class annotated with `@Configuration` and it has a method annotated with `@Bean`. I don't want it to be instantiated (it's not needed and introduces dependency on a **Spring Boot**, which I don't use.

Unfortunately this `@Configuration`-annotated class is used elsewhere in the library (required by the class type, not interface type, so I need to instantiate exactly this class).

I exluded it's package from auto-scanning, I'm not importing it directly. Just constructing it by hand and registering in own configuration as a bean.

So, to make story short - I need to register a bean, but exclude it from annotation scnanning (to not process it's `@Bean`-annotated methods). Any way for doing this?

Comment: You can refer the below link .Hope it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscanhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan

Comment: @JSav Please read the problem description. I'm not auto-scanning the package, I'm creating a bean by-hand and just because it's injected into container, it's being processed.

Comment: @RafałWrzeszcz, what is it mean "registering a bean without annotation scanning" ? Then how can u register it ? You need a method with '@Bean' annotation that crate and instance of the class, or annotate the class with '@Componen', '@Service' etc. annotation for annotation scanning to find it ?

Comment: Does `@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = TheBean.class) )` will help you?

Comment: @GokhanOner I *DO NOT* want it to be registered.

Comment: @RaeBurawes Please read - it's not imported through scanning.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean you have library in your maven, gradle, then you can exclude spring beans from being initialized. I found [exclude @Component from @ComponentScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan)

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"com.example"},
    excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(
            type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
            value = Foo.class)})
public class MySpringConfiguration {

}
```

And if you do not want to include transitive dependencies, thus you do not want your dependency to add other dependencies it uses, you have to exclude them from your dependncy (in maven, gradle).

Comment: Hi, How can I say to spring to use just the bean that I have in my maven without use the other with the same name?

Comment: @Primery annotation in your Bean