# Using ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider and excluding special directory

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, classpath, scanning

I'd like to use the `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` for searching different subclasses of one class. But I need to exclude a special directory in this case.

Example:

**Directories/Packages:**

`src/main/java/frstPck/scndPck`
`src/test/java/frstPck/scndPck`

Code for scanning:

```
public static void example() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(Super.class));

    Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents("frstPck/scndPck");
    for (BeanDefinition component : components) {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(component.getBeanClassName());
        System.out.print(cls.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the classpathscanning would also find subclasses of `src/test/java` and exactly this should not happen. Is there any possibility to exclude those?

Comment: Can't you use excludeFilters of componentScan e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan ?

Comment: I already saw the exclude filters but I didn't find a way to use them receiving the expected solution.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but the answer can help others.

If yours test classes names have the word "Test" at the end as the default, you can exclude them by making a filter by the name like this:

```
provider.addExcludeFilter(new RegexPatternTypeFilter(Pattern.compile(".*Test")))
```

Then it will look like this:

```
public static void example() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(Super.class));
    provider.addExcludeFilter(new RegexPatternTypeFilter(Pattern.compile(".*Test")));

    Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents("frstPck/scndPck");
    for (BeanDefinition component : components) {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(component.getBeanClassName());
        System.out.print(cls.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```