# How to mock a class that been annotated with Primary

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I have :

- an interface : `EntityService`
- a first implementation : `EntityServiceImpl` - This class is annotated with `@Primary`
- an other one : `EntityServiceClientImpl`
- and a controller that has this field `@Autowired EntityService`

I would like to do a test on this controller and for this test to be unitary I mock `EntityService`.

So of course this code does not work because Spring detects two beans annotated with Primary :

```
@Configuration
class EntityControllerTestConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    EntityService entityService() {
        return mock(EntityService.class);
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = EntityControllerTestConfig.class)
public class EntityControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private EntityService entityService;
```

...

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= "com.company.app")
@EntityScan (basePackages = {"com.company.app" }, basePackageClasses = {Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.company.app")
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I tried to find an other way to mock and to exclude `EntityServiceClient` on test configuration but i was not able to mock. (cf : [exclude @Component from @ComponentScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found that solution : a spring context (with controller, controllerAdvice and mock of service) and not a spring boot context

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class EntityControllerTest {

    @Configuration
    public static class EntityControllerTestConfig {
        @Bean
        public EntityService entityService() {
            return mock(EntityService.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public EntityController entityController() {
            return new EntityController(entityService());
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private EntityService entityService;

    @Autowired
    private EntityController entityController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws DomaineException {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(entityController)
            .setControllerAdvice(new myControllerAdvice())
            .build();
```

NB : Since Spring 4.2 you can set your ControllerAdvice like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it slightly differently and combine [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) with [`@MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) annotation to test just the controller with it's own minimal context.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = EntityController.class)
public class EntityControllerTest {

  @MockBean
  private EntityService entityService;

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;
```

In this example `EntityService` will be mocked while `MockMvc` can be used to assert the request mappings in controller.

Comment: Hi Karol,
That did not worked (`Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test`).
Is it possible to mock a bean after the initialisation ?

Comment: @DamDam you are using `@SpringBootApplication` and this one provides `@SpringBootConfiguration`. You must have set up the project in a very unusual way that it doesn't work out of the box. Check https://start.spring.io/ to get a fresh clean project setup.