# ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class/spring bean A inside package a.b.c in a common artifact which is imported as a dependency in my project. There is the same class A defined in my project as well but in different packages lets say x.y.z. So when I run the spring boot app, it fails with the following exception. Is there any way to exclude the component A which is present in the common library, but I need other components present in the other library. I tried excluding using regex but still the same error.

````
      "message": "Annotation-specified bean name 'A' for bean class [a.b.c.A] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [x.y.z.A]",
      "name": "org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException",
      "extendedStackTrace": [
        {
          "class": "org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner",
          "method": "checkCandidate",
          "file": "ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java",
          "line": 345,
          "exact": false,
          "location": "spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/",
          "version": "4.3.6.RELEASE"```
````

Comment: Sure there is, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan

Comment: ```@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"
        "a.b"}
    , excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "a\\.b\\.c\\.*")```

    I am excluding this way but this error is still there @ekalin

Comment: is this something  to do with spring version?

Comment: is the class Definition the same or only the name is the same?

Comment: try @ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(a.b.c.A.class)); Also check by mistake you might have imported wrong package.