# Spring Data JDBC Testcontainers DataSource

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers, spring-data-jdbc

With spring boot + spring data jdbc i have to wire the `DataSource` bean by myself. Like so:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(this.environment.getRequiredProperty("url"));
        hikariConfig.setUsername("user");
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("password");
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }
```

When i want to use testcontainers for my tests i have to declare a `DataSource` bean as well:

```
@Bean
        @Primary
        DataSource testDataSource() {

            if (POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER == null) {
                PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("postgres").withTag("9.6.12"));
                container.withInitScript("schema.sql");
                container.start();
                POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER = container;
            }
            PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
            dataSource.setUrl(POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl());
            dataSource.setUser(POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER.getUsername());
            dataSource.setPassword(POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER.getPassword());

            return dataSource;
        }
```

Using my tests with `SpringBootTest` i have to `ComponentScan` nearly all packages because i don´t want to mock all other beans.
So my question is:
Can i somehow exclude the main `DataSource` only for test cases?
(My current workaround is to define the test `DataSource` as `Primary`)
But nevertheless i have two `DataSource` beans in my `Context` even if i only need one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exclude @Component from @ComponentScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. By the way. Have you checked out Wim Deblauwe's answer below? There is no dedicated `DataSource` declared in this code. Isn´t this oblitgatory in Spring Data JDBC? I´m just curious ...

Comment: Spring Boot can create your datasource, which seems to get utilized with Wims answer, where the necessary information is configured in the dynamic property source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example at https://github.com/wearearima/spring-data-jdbc-testcontainers seems to indicate that it is not needed to define your own DataSource at all.

See https://github.com/wearearima/spring-data-jdbc-testcontainers/blob/master/src/test/java/eu/arima/springdatajdbctestcontainers/AccountRepositoryTest.java#L94 how to pass the properties of the TestContainers managed database to Spring Boot:

```
 @DynamicPropertySource
    static void postgresqlProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgresqlContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgresqlContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgresqlContainer::getPassword);
    }
```

Comment: Very nice. I can´t find a dedicated spring-data-jdbc `DataSource` bean in your code. Does this line the job? https://github.com/wearearima/spring-data-jdbc-testcontainers/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/arima/springdatajdbctestcontainers/SpringDataJdbcTestcontainersApplication.java#L15

Comment: It is not my code, just something I found googling, so I can't help you on that unfortunately.