# Define Spring beans in library and exclude them from ComponentScan

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm writing a library for two applications A and B. Application A defines beans with XML (without component scanning) and B uses annotations and component scanning. I want to let the library define some beans that both A and B can include. However, A and B should *only* include those beans when they are started in a specific Spring profile (let's say `my_profile`).

The TLDR question is: is there a way to do the above without referencing `my_profile` in the library and without having to explicitly exclude the library from B's component scan?

Currently, the beans in the library are defined as @Bean methods in a @Configuration class, like this:

```
@Configuration
open class LibraryConfig {
  @Bean
  open fun libraryBean() = ...
}
```

Now in application A, in XML, I can do this:

```
<beans profile="my_profile">
    <bean class="com.package.LibraryConfig" />
</beans>
```

And that works.
In application B, that uses annotations, I *would like* to do something like this:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("my_profile")
@Import(LibraryConfig::class)
open class MyProfileConfig
```

But since LibraryConfig is also annotated with @Configuration, it will *always* be found by the component scanning. So this approach to make it conditional doesn't work.

Approaches I have considered:

1. Simply include the profile in a @Profile on the LibraryConfig. I don't want to do this because the library should not be aware of the profiles of its consumers.
2. Explicitly exclude the LibraryConfig from the @ComponentScan of project B. The drawback here is that we have projects C D and E too, that will *not* use `my_profile`. I want to be able to include the library there anyway without having to explicitly exclude a part of it.

So I'm looking for a way to create a 'configuration' class that can only be explicitly included. Or any other elegant way to do the above. Can it be done?

Comment: Have you tried excluding the bean or package from componentscanning? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan

Comment: Yes, see point 2 of the approaches I've considered. :) If I go that route, I'm forced to add this exclusion to every application I want to include this library in. That's doable, of course, but cumbersome. It would be much more convenient if I could add a dependency on my library to any project without any special work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some ways to exclude the library package from project A or B's component scan without explicitly stating that the package is to be excluded.

**Use a different package root for your library**
The most straightforward option is to use a different package root for the library than the project uses. Since the [`@SpringBootApplication`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.java#L57) annotation is meta-annotated with `@ComponentScan`, if `@ComponentScan`'s attributes `basePackageClasses` or `basePackages` have not been specified, the package name of the annotated class is used as root package to use for component scanning [(source)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html):

> Configures component scanning directives for use with @Configuration classes. Provides support parallel with Spring XML's context:component-scan element. Either basePackageClasses() or basePackages() (or its alias value()) may be specified to define specific packages to scan. If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation.

For instance, if a `@SpringBootApplication` annotated root class is located in package `com.example.somepackage`:

```java
package com.example.somepackage;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    ...
}
```

The base package root `com.example.somepackage` will be used as the root for component scanning. Using `com.example.library` instead of `com.example.somepackage.library` *should* exclude the library from being included in the component scanning.

**Make use of `ConditionalOn` annotations in the Library**
If the method above doesn't work and the configuration is still automatically included during component scanning, a slightly less invasive way when compared to using profiles is adding `@ConditionalOnX` annotations to your configuration class, such as:

[**ConditionalOnProperty**](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty)

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "yourlibrary", name = "enabled", havingValue="true")
```

The projects relying on the library will now need to include the property `yourlibrary.enabled=true`.

More info on the several `@ConditionalOn` annotations can be found [here](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-conditionals/).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the first method, but in general I think that's the right approach if you make a generic library. For our situation, because it's an internal library, it isn't really feasible, so I'm going for the second method.
The library doesn't use Spring Boot, so it seems I can only use the generic `@Conditional` annotation. So that's what I'll do.